# Hello,I am new to VHDL programming please help me out with these errors

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, state-machine

I don't know why its showing error although syntax seems to be right.

I'm t rying to program sramctl where address adds_in is input address and sram_adds output address I am just mapping the address and have not consider the data bus.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sramctrl is
port(clk,adsn,blastn,lwdrn,lhold:in std_logic;
 adds_in :in std_logic_vector(9 downto 2);          

 adds_4msb:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 28);
 readyn,btermn,sramcsn,sramoen,lholda :out std_logic;
 sram_adds:out std_logic_vector(9 downto 2));
 end sramctrl;
architecture behavioral of sramctrl is
type state_type is(s0,s1,s2);
signal state:state_type;
begin
process(clk,adsn,blastn,lwdrn,lhold,adds_in,adds_4msb)
begin
    variable sa:std_logic:='0';
    variable a31_a28 :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    variable temp:std_logic_vector(9 downto 2):="00000000";
    if(rising_edge(clk))then
        if ((not adsn) and (adds_4msb="0000"))then         
        a31_28 := adds_4msb; 
        end if;
        if (lhold='1')then
            lholda<='1';
        else
             lholda<='0';
        end if;
        sa:=lhold and lholda ;
        case state is
            when s0=>sramoen<='1';
                    sramcsn<='1';
                    readyn<='1';
                    btermn<='1';
                    if((not adsn) and (not adds_4msb) and sa)then
                        temp:=adds_in;
                            if(lwdrn='1')then
                                state<=s1;
                                ready<='0';
                            else
                                state<=s2;
                            end if;
                    else
                        state<=s0;
                    end if;
                when s1=>sramoen<='1';
                        sramcsn<='0';
                        if(lwdrn and (not blastn) and sa)then
                            sram_adds<=temp;
                            readyn<='1';
                            btermn<='1';
                            state<=s0;
                        elsif(lwdrn and blastn and sa)then
                            if(temp=X"fe")then
                                sram_adds<=temp;
                                temp:=temp+1;
                                btermn<='0';
                                readyn<='0';
                                state<=s1;
                            elsif(temp=X"ff")then
                                sram_adds<=temp;
                                btermn<='1';
                                readyn<='1';
                                state<=s0;
                            else
                                sram_adds<=temp;
                                temp:=temp+1;
                                btermn<='1';
                                readyn<='0';
                                state<=s1;
                            end if;
                        else
                            state<=s2;
                        end if;
             when s2=>sramoen<='0';
                      sramcsn<='0';
                     if((not lwdrn) and (not blastn) and sa)then
                        sram_adds<=temp;
                        readyn<='1';
                        btermn<='1';
                        state<=s0;
                    elsif((not lwdrn) and blastn and sa)then
                        if(temp=X"fe")then
                            sram_adds<=temp;
                            temp:=temp+1;
                            btermn<='0';
                            readyn<='0';
                            state<=s2;
                        elsif(temp=X"ff")then
                            sram_adds<=temp;
                            btermn<='1';
                            readyn<='1';
                            state<=s0;
                        else
                            sram_adds<=temp;
                            temp:=temp+1;
                            btermn<='1';
                            readyn<='0';
                            state<=s2;
                        end if;
                    else
                     state<=s2;
                    end if;
       when others =>state<=s0;
      end case;
      end if;
      end process;
      end behavioral ;
```

I couldn't find a solution please help me out. Errors it has popped:

> COMP96 Compile Architecture "behavioral" of Entity "sramctrl"
>    COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0019: "Keyword 'end' expected." "design.vhd" 18 9
>   COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0019: "Keyword 'end' expected." "design.vhd" 19 3
>   COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0016: "Design unit declaration expected." "design.vhd"

Comment: Inside the process variables must be declared before `begin` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your syntax isn't correct.

As noted by Amir :

```
process(clk,adsn,blastn,lwdrn,lhold,adds_in,adds_4msb)
begin
    variable sa:std_logic:='0';
    variable a31_a28 :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    variable temp:std_logic_vector(9 downto 2):="00000000";
```

Should be:

```
process(clk,adsn,blastn,lwdrn,lhold,adds_in,adds_4msb)
    variable sa:std_logic:='0';
    variable a31_a28 :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    variable temp:std_logic_vector(9 downto 2):="00000000";
begin
```

`begin` separates the process declarative part from the process statement part here.

Also, here:

```
        if ((not adsn) and (adds_4msb="0000"))then
```

There isn't an `and` operator that ANDs a std_logic and a boolean (result of the right expression).`not` is not a logical reduction operator, it returns a std_logic in this case.

should be along the lines of:

```
        if adsn = '0' and adds_4msb = "0000" then
```

Which ANDs two boolean results. Notice the corrected spelling of `adds_4msb`.

The next line:

```
        a31_28 := adds_4msb;
```

has a misspelling, that should be a31_a28.

And here::

```
        if lhold = '1' then
            lholda <= '1';
        else
             lholda <= '0';
        end if;
        sa := lhold and lholda ;
```

`lholda` is an output and in some tools not IEEE Std 1076-2008 compliant can not be read.  It also produces a `sa` that's simply delayed by one delta simulation cycle (no time advancing) and has no meaning other that to trim a delta cycle off the end of `holda` for `sa` or off the beginning of `lhold`.  If you're counting on that delta cycle hold over not being there you have a defective design.  Delta cycles emulate parallelism and variables shouldn't be counted on for timing relationships.  This would imply you don't have a synthesis eligible model of sram_ctl.  Synthesis would see `lhold` and `lholda` as one and the same, and `sa` as a different name for the same thing.

Here:

```
                                ready<='0';
```

There is no signal `ready` present in your design.

And:

```
                        if(lwdrn and (not blastn) and sa)then
```

as well as:

```
                        elsif(lwdrn and blastn and sa)then
```

You're trying to produce a boolean condition with logic operators.  (All those parentheses are also redundant) try conditional testing the two expressions to a std_logic value.

These two conditions show up two places each.

And:

```
                                temp:=temp+1;
```

There is no adding operator "+" directly visible (two places).  You should either be using package std_logic_unsigned or `temp` should be an unsigned and you should be using package numeric_std (requiring a type conversion when assigning to `sram_adds`).

Comment: Any suggestions of resources regarding the VHDL programming ?

Comment: "Any suggestions of resources regarding the VHDL programming ?" Asking for a resource outside of Stackoverflow isn't an appropriate question.  See [Some questions are still off-topic...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on the What questions can I ask here page.  This is a place to get specific answers to specific questions and not general answers to general questions.  Try googling *VHDL cheatsheet*.